# My variable for the volume in sonic pi is not changing - why?

Tags: ruby, sonic-pi

I have some sonic pi code, and it is supposed to do a melody 8 times and play softer each time. However, it is not paying attention to the variable. Am I doing it wrong?

```
8.times do
  i = 1
  play 50, amp: 0.1 * i
  sleep 0.25
  play 55, amp: 0.2 * i
  sleep 0.25
  play 57, amp: 0.4 * i
  sleep 0.25
  play 62, amp: i
  i = i - 0.125
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problems

You have at least three problems with your code:

1. Your *i* variable is block-local, so it isn't propagating outside of your block. This may not be a significant problem, but it makes it harder to debug your code.
2. You are explicitly resetting the value of *i* at the top of each loop with `i = 1`.
3. The block doesn't memoize the value of *i* between calls to the block, so putting `i ||= 1.0` at the top of the block doesn't really work either because *i* is always nil at the start of each loop.

Consider this minimal example of your existing code:

```
8.times { i = 1; i -= 0.125 }
i # NameError (undefined local variable or method `i' for main:Object)
```

Even if you introspect *i* within the block, you'll see that it never decrements with the current logic.

### Solutions

The easiest way to fix your issues is to set the initial value of *i* outside your block. For example:

```
i = 1.0

8.times do
  i -= 0.125
  p i
end

i
#=> 0.0
```

With the [Kernel#p](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Kernel.html#method-i-p) statement, you can see the numbers counting down:

> ```
> 0.875
> 0.75
> 0.625
> 0.5
> 0.375
> 0.25
> 0.125
> 0.0
> ```

You can also see that you variable is now accessible outside of the block, and no longer returns a NameError when you access it after the block exits.

```
i
#=> 0.0
```

Comment: You know what? That actually makes a lot of sense. I realize that now. Thanks for your answer!